# Is there any way to manually programatically create HttpSession in the server without neccessety of sending request?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, testing, session-cookies

I am coding on java using the Spring boot application.

I have the following method in Controller:

```
 getCustomerById();
```

and two Filters for the request that executed in the following order:

1. CheckSessionFilter that checks whether a session exists for the request
2. CheckCustomerStatusFilter that check internal status for customer

I need to implement an integration test for the getCustomerById() that checks the behavior when a request comes to CheckCustomerStatusFilter. For that I need to send a request with the valid HttpSession in cookies; But how to get this active session without doing additional requests from my application responsible for the session creation. Is there any way to manually create the HttpSession using Servlet API and then just send request to the test server with the SESSION in the cookie?

I do my integration test by fully launching Spring context and sending request to endpoint handled by getCustomerById() method:

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = Runner.class, webEnvironment =
        SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class CustomerFiltersTest {


    @Autowired
    TestRestTemplate testRestTemplate;
 
    @SpyBean
    CheckSessionFilter checkSessionFilter;
    @SpyBean
    CheckCustomerStatusFilter checkCustomerStatusFilter;

    @Test
    public void requestToGetCustomerByIdEndpoint_shouldGoThroughCheckCustomerStatusFilter() throws Exception {
        final String host = "http://localhost:" + port;
        HttpEntity<?> entity = new HttpEntity(null, null);
        String requestUrl = host + CUSTOMER_BY_ID_URL;

        testRestTemplate.exchange(
                requestUrl,
                HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
       


        verify(checkSessionFilter, times(1)).doFilter(any(), any(), any());
        verify(checkCustomerStatusFilter, times(1)).doFilter(any(), any(), any());

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try mocking the HttpSession Object.